# Probability of winning one of $n$ prizes in a lottery if you buy $t$ tickets

Tags: probability, statistics

I was thinking about how to calculate the scenario outlined in the title - we take part in a lottery, there is $n$ prizes to be drawn and we decide to buy $t$ tickets to have larger chances of securing a win - what is the probability that we win one of them?

Were the question based on just "whether or not we're drawn", this would just be $\frac{t}{k}$ where $k$ is the total of tickets bougth by all the players but since there are multiple prizes, in fact we first have the odds of $\frac{t}{k}$, then $\frac{t}{k-1}$ and so on up until $\frac{t}{k-n}$.

But if we just sum them so that we end up with something like: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{t}{k-i}$ which would actually *exceed* $1$ in a case like: ${t=10, k=12, n=5}$. So how should you overcome this? What would be the correct formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to overcome anything. You will always win when you have $t=10$, $k=12$ and $n=5$. In fact, whenever $n>k-t$, you are guaranteed to win at least one prize.

Think of it this way: If there are $k-t+1$ prizes to be drawn, even if you didn't win a prize in the first $k-t$ draws, you would be the guaranteed winner of the next draw, since you are the only one still holding a ticket that hasn't been drawn yet.

EDIT (And actual answer to the problem)
The problem is that the probability of winning is not
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t}{k-i},\;\;\;(1)$$
as you claim in your question, but
$$1-\prod^{n-1}_{i=0}\frac{k-(t+i)}{k-i}.\;\;\;(2)$$
In (1), by just adding the probabilities of winning at the $i$-th draw, you do not take into account the cases, in which you already win a prize at a previous draw. If you want to easily calculate the probability of winning at least once, you can do that with (2).

Comment: I know I am guaranteed to win in the example and that's precisely what I pinpointed as the problem - the probability should evaluate to 1, then, not something larger :)

Comment: @Straightfw I hope to have addressed your concerns about my answer adequately.

Comment: oooh I see, makes perfect sense, thank you a lot :) One quick question to wrap things up if I may - the formula calculates the probability of winning _at least_ once but would it also be correct in lotteries where you can _only_ win once (e.g. if you win one of the prizes, you're not being in the draw for the other ones)? Of course for simplicity sake we would assume that all the other tickets are unique (1 ticket per 1 person) and only we bought more than one so as not to deal with how many tickets of other players are removed from the pool after each draw.

Comment: @Straightfw Yes, in that case (2) will also give you the probability of winning a prize (but not the probability of winning exactly once in a lottery with the properties described in your question).

Comment: Got it, thank you very much :)